# How do RethinkDB, Laravel, and Ratchet work together?

Tags: laravel-5, chat, real-time, rethinkdb, ratchet

## Situation

Am trying to build a real-time chat toy app using the following technology stack

- RethinkDB
- Laravel 5
- Ratchet

## What I perceive to be the conceptual situation

[image]

The green arrows represent the real-time exchange of data.

The black arrows represent other non real-time requests and exchange of data.

## My question

I was wondering if my understanding of the implementation of chat using the technology stack is correct based on the diagram?

if there are inaccuracies, what would they be?

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation seems correct, although I would not suggest using the websocket to send data to but only to distribute live data to all subscribers of a channel. 
To do this,  get an API(preferably)  going to receive new posts/chats/users. 
And use a push server to send the data received to the socket. 
A push server is just an in between of the app and websocket that allows php(laravel)  to access the socket easily.

Edit: to elaborate
[image]

To retry explaining this to you.
All clients listen to the WebScoket Server. This is a connection which is passive and they will only receive messages from the socket according to what topics/subscriptions they have.

When someone wants to send a message(in case of a chat application) they send it to an API to check if the right user sent it, maybe even use apikeys or other means of security.

Once the message is received in the API then the API wants to distribite it to all listening clients for that chat room/topic/subscription.

So the message is forwarded to the pushserver which is an in between of the backend (API, controllers) and the WebSocket (subscriptions, topics).

The pushserver forwards the message to the WebSocket afterwards and then the WebSocket distibutes the message to the correct listeners.

Advantages of using an API:

- Security
- Scalability

Comment: i still don't quite "grok" what you are saying. can help by drawing some diagrams?